# Stripping all but specified debug information from executable

Tags: linux, gdb, elf, gnu-assembler, binutils

I'm developing a shared library for Linux that spawns some threads I want to label in the debugger.

I've read this can be done by writing to /proc/[PID]/tasks/[TID]/comm, but this isn't working (I'm targeting an older libc). I also want to be able to assign names longer than the comm limit.

My plan was to auto-load a Python script to do this by placing it in the [.debug_gdb_scripts section](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/dotdebug_005fgdb_005fscripts-section.html).

However I want to strip debug information besides the script and what it needs.
I've tried using the --keep-symbol option but all of the debug sections (include .debug_gdb_scripts) are still removed.

Is there some way to keep these?

Answer (score 2):

One idea that comes to mind is to strip your program first, and then add the `.debug_gdb_scripts` afterwards, using `objcopy`.

Another way might be to put `.debug_gdb_scripts` inside the [mini debug section](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/MiniDebugInfo.html).  I think this should work ok, though it is a bit weird -- I think the first approach is more sound.

Yet another option is to just do the standard thing and strip all the debuginfo to a separate debuginfo file, which you would then use when debugging.  However from your question I assume there is some reason you don't want to do this.

Comment: I want to distribute a shared library where users can set breakpoints and print argument information on a few functions but strip symbol/debug info for everything else. It sounds like that may be impossible.

Comment: It's definitely difficult, I think, because you'd want to ship the DWARF for the types and some info for those functions but not for others.